# django 1.9 Cannot resolve keyword 'roomtype' into field

Tags: django, search, admin

I'm trying to make a search field in admin panel searching correct. Here is my code

models.py

```
class Hotel(ServioResource):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Name'))

class RoomType(ServioResource):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(
        Hotel, related_name='room_types', verbose_name=_('Hotel'))
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(RoomType)
class RoomTypeAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    list_select_related = ('hotel',)
    list_display = ('id', 'hotel', 'class_name')
    search_fields = ['roomtype__hotel__hotel__name']
    list_filter = ('hotel',)
    group_fieldsets = True
    inlines = [
        RoomTypeImageTabular,
    ]
```

Comment: I think you might want `hotel__name` instead of `roomtype__hotel__hotel__name`.

Comment: hotel__name -- search is always "0"

Comment: I don't know why that does not give any search results, but `'roomtype__hotel__hotel__name'` definitely looks wrong. It is the model admin for the `RoomType` model, so having `roomtype` doesn't make sense, and I can't see any reason to repeat `hotel`.

Comment: The whole error for "cannot resolve keyword" normally gives you a list of allowed keywords, please include the full traceback

Comment: here are keywords --- Cannot resolve keyword 'roomtype' into field. Choices are: area, area_en, area_ru, area_uk, class_name, class_name_en, class_name_ru, class_name_uk, description, description_en, description_ru, description_uk, hotel, hotel_id, id, images, main_places_count, max_additional_places_count, max_places, published, roomreservation, servio_id  -- if I try to use such key i have such mistake - Related Field got invalid lookup: hotel_id - foe example

Comment: The keywords would imply that Alasdair was correct, you should be using hotel as per the first comment (Also, use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41871131/edit) button to update your question)